# How to connect to virtual serial port using pyserial?

Tags: python, pyserial

I would like to send commands from my python app to Klipper via /tmp/printer file. I’m trying to use pyserial library, but it don’t work at all.

**What I can do:**
I can connect correctly using pyserial miniterm with different baudrates (eg. 9600, 38400, 250000). In this case I can home, move, etc.

**What I can’t do:**

1. Connect using python’s terminal.

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/tmp/printer', 38400)
>>> ser.is_open
True
>>> ser
Serial<id=0xf6f66f70, open=True>(port='/tmp/printer', baudrate=38400, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
>>> ser.write(b'G28 X')
5
>>> ser.close()
```

Nothing happened.

2. Connect using my app

```
def send_gcode(gcode):
    # Send gcode in bytes
    printer_serial.open()
    time.sleep(2)
    print(printer_serial)
    printer_serial.write(gcode.encode())
    print('Command sended')
    line = printer_serial.readline()
    print(line)
    printer_serial.close()
```

No reaction…

**Question:**
Where should I look for reason of problem?

Comment: You probably need to send a line ending (`\r` or `\n`) before the command is acted on.

Comment: Good point! :) Thank you